# Right side Face detection with EmguCv

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

**Hello everybody,**
I works on a face detection and recognizing project with EmguCv in C#, so i already do some steps:
-detect front face and left face
-recognize faces

*but the problem* it when i want to detect right side of face it didn't work because the classifier profileface.xml just work for left side, i found some ideas for do a mirror but i have no idea how to do it.

so plz plz if some one have any idea to do it i will be very happy.

Mohammed Hassar.

Answer (score 0):

there's a flip() function for this:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#flip

Comment: Thnx bro, the problem it how can you mirror the input image from web camera and use it with profilface.xml