# Compare a side face with front using Face - API (MS Cognitive Services)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am working on identifying a face against set of faces in database using MS Cognitive Services - Face API.

If the input face is a side face then it throws,

```
The length of faceids is not in a valid range.
```

error.

Is it possible to compare a side face with front one using Face - API?

Thanks.

Note: There is a question on EmguCV([Right side Face detection with EmguCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030377/right-side-face-detection-with-emgucv)) for the same but I am using MS Cognitive Services Face API.

Answer (score 0):

Saravanan,

You may have already figured this out, but I hit a similar issue with calling the Face Group API:

```
GroupResult x = await faceServiceClient.GroupAsync(values);
```

When "values" in this example only contained one FaceID I got this error. In my case it was a mistake on my part, as it is impossible to group only one face. The error message was a bit cryptic, though, and it took me a while to figure it out. This may help someone else in the future.